# What is the maximum horizontal distance that can be covered with elytra?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the maximum distance one could travel with elytra in Minecraft before it needs to be repaired? Assume that it has Unbreaking III on it. If it matters, I play on Minecraft Bedrock.

Partially, I want to know this so I can plan on how far from my base I can regularly expect to explore without needing to stop to mend my elytra, but I'm also just curious.

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Elytra#Durability_and_Repair), you can have a flight time of up to 28 minutes and 44 seconds, but I don't see a good way to convert that to a distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by @pinckerman provided a lower bound to the distance that can be covered using elytra, and it led me to do some more research and eventually I landed on [this page in the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Transportation).

From the Wiki:

> **Elytra:**
> **Conditions:** Gliding at 0° pitch
> **Average Speed:** 30 m/s

Using this information, I was able to calculate an approximation of how far you could travel with elytra enchanted with Unbreaking 3 and came up with **51,720 blocks**.

Using additional data from the same Wiki article, you could travel **57,754 blocks using continuous rocket boosts.**

If you were extremely lucky and it was raining for the entire trip, then you could travel **215,500 blocks using a trident with Riptide III enchantment.**

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Elytra#Speed_and_altitude), Elytra has a minimum speed of about 7.2 m/s.

Knowing that Minecraft uses the metric system, and each block is considered to be 1 cubic meter ([source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Measuring_distance#Metric_units)), we can do some easy math:

28min 44s is 1724 seconds, this means that an Elytra will let you travel at least 12412.8 blocks (assuming that they are on a superflat world).

Comment: The linked article suggests without enhancements you can reach more than 10,000 blocks of distance and that the enhancements substantially increase that.  Also wondering how altitude figures in since you can’t actually fly in a straight line and can reach maybe 1100 block distance per flight.